# In JS can I require() only an export from a module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, requirejs

In other words can I do this :

```
import Binance from 'binance-api-node'

const client = Binance()
```

with a require() statement ??

The above code needs to be in a small module I have to write so I cannot use import

Comment: Perhaps: `const Binance - require('binance-api-node').Binance;`  Would actually need to see the source for the 'binance-api-node' module to know for sure (but I can't find it on Github).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const Binance = require('binance-api-node').default;

const client = Binance();
```

Comment: I tried this but I get an error "TypeError: Binance is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ES modules try this:

```js
import Binance from 'binance-api-node'
const client = Binance.default()
```